# How to update a column based on inserted ids when using insert select?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to update a column in the one table with the ids generated after an insert into another table. This is what I have:

```
    tbl1 (id, tbl2id, col1, col2)
    tbl2 (id, col1, col2)

    insert into tbl2
    select col1, col2
    from tbl1
    where tbl1.tbl2id is null
```

At this point I need to populate tbl1.tbl2id with the id for all the rows that were inserted by the above insert statement, so that if the above insert statement is run again, I will not have duplicates in tbl2.  I'm on SQL Server 2005.

Comment: If you are populating a table from data inserted in to a different table, why not use a trigger to perform the insert? You will have all the inserted data available in the `inserted` table of the trigger.

Comment: I'm modifying an existing stored proc that's pretty long, so I was wondering if there is way to do it from the sproc itself.  Is it easy to convert a sproc to a trigger?

Comment: You can think of a trigger as a stored proc called after `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` (or any combination of the three). Have a look at the syntax of the trigger sql: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: If you want help restructuring a large procedure you will have to post all the code, otherwise it will be hard to suggest optimisations that do not affect the outcome of the entire procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the OUTPUT clause and a Temp Table.

OUTPUT clause info is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

It should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE #NewIDs (Tbl1Col1 INT, Tbl2ID INT)

insert into tbl2 (col1, col2)
OUTPUT inserted.col1, inserted.id INTO #NewIDs (Tbl1Col1, Tbl2ID)
  select col1, col2  
  from tbl1  
  where tbl1.tbl2id is null

UPDATE t
SET    t.tbl2id = tmp.Tbl2ID
FROM   Tbl1 t
INNER JOIN   #NewIDs tmp
        ON   tmp.Tbl1Col1 = t.Col1
```

The real trick is making sure that one of the fields that you are inserting into Table2 from Table2 can be used to JOIN on so hopefully it is unique, or unique enough.  The only real complication is that the ID for Table 1 is not part of the query doing the INSERT so it is not available to the OUTPUT clause.

Comment: Can you do this on SQL Server 2005?

Comment: @Prabhu: In fact you can, I thought that too but the `OUTPUT` keyword is available in 2005: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: I'm not sure I have a unique column available that I can use to join.

Comment: @Prabhu, would the combination of any/all columns being inserted into Table2 be a unique set? If so, put them all into the Temp Table and then JOIN on all of them.  I have done that myself before.

Answer (score 0):

Using a trigger you could do

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name 
ON tbl2
AFTER INSERT
AS 
     INSERT tbl1 (tbl2id, col1, col2)
     SELECT id, col1, col2 
     FROM inserted
```

Comment: Table1 is not being inserted into in his scenario, it is Table2.  Also, Table1 has a Table2ID column that is not being populated in this case.

Comment: @srutzky: Thanks, I got the tables the wrong way round. Have edited my answer.

Comment: @Tony, so I can keep my stored proc as is and just introduce this trigger?  So after the insert happens in my stored proc, this trigger will automatically update my table?

Comment: @Prabhu: Yes, as long as there is nothing else modifying the data after that, as I said in the comment on your question you have to take in to account all the modifications made by the procedure. The `inserted` table will contain all the rows inserted in to `tbl2` and will be run `AFTER` the insert completes.

Comment: @Tony--do triggers need any special permissions? Also, where do they reside?  After creating them how can I locate them in mgmt studio? Thanks.

Comment: @Prabhu: If you can create a table then you have permission to create a trigger on it. You might need to check BOL to see about the permission necessary to modify an existing table. Just try executing the `CREATE TRIGGER ...` statement and you will soon see :) After creating a trigger expand the tree under the table in Managment Studio, you should see a `Triggers` folder: e.g. http://www.mssqltips.com/tipImages/1380_SQLServer2005Triggers_1.gif

Comment: While I am not a fan of Triggers for anything outside of Auditing and Referential Integrity, this solution might work IF it is safe to say that ALL inserts into Table2 should take this action. Also, there are no special permissions for Triggers, but Table1 will now need direct INSERT permissions for whoever (login or role) is running an INSERT against Table2 since this is not like a Stored Proc that assumes the permissions granted to the Proc itself.